# Differentiation of subtraction

Tags: functions, derivatives, continuity

I've got an exercise to do and I don't really know what to do.

Exercise : We've got function $f$, where $f(a) = 0$ and $f'(a)$ exists. Also we got function $g$ which is continuous. Does exist $(f-g)'(a)$? Explain it.

My opinion is that exists, but I've got no idea how should I explain it. Some help? Thank you.

Comment: Added you an answer down below of why this derivative does not exist. Make sure you ask anything you don't understand and approve any answer that fits you so that the thread goes down as "answered".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(a)=0$ and $\exists f'(a)$.

The expression : $(f-g)'(a)$ is : $f'(a) - g'(a)$.

You cannot say that this derivative exists, if $g$ is not differentiable at $a$. In your question's body, you have only stated that $f$ is differentiable and that $g$ is only continuous. Thus, no, you cannot say generally that $\exists (f-g)'(a)$.

Comment: I know, but I'm really sure that has something do with that f(a) = 0.

Comment: Nothing, you don't even need it to be honest since $g$ is not differentiable ... It's just there to complicate your mind.

Comment: Our teacher is that kind of man who likes to complicate your mind.

Comment: Hahaha! Well, if the question is exactly as you written it, then you do not know anything about the derivative of $g$ and hence you got the answer :)

Comment: I was affraid that $f(x) = 0$ got something to do with the entire exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Not true, example: take $f=0$, $g=|x|$ and $a=0$.

Comment: What a simple but convincing counterexample. It'd be better if you can format it nicely.

Answer (score -1):

Is $g$ differentiable?  That information is not given.  It is possible for $g$ to be continous but not differentiable.

Anyway differentiation is "linear", in that $(f-g)'(a)$ = $f'(a) - g'(a).$
So, if $g'(a)$ exists (and $f'(a)$ exists which is given) then $(f-g)'(a)$ exists.

But if $g'(a)$ does not exist, then $(f-g)'(a)$ does not exist.

Comment: A similar answer was added before, so why add a same one again ?

Comment: Nothing about function $g$, only that is continuous. But what about f(a) = 0. Why he gave this information?

Comment: @CharalamposFilippatos 3 answers were written within 2 minutes of one another.

Comment: f(a) = 0  is irrelevant.

Comment: So it is useless.

Comment: I don't know if useless is the right word.  There is often irrelevant information.  It is important to know what is and what is not important for the task at hand.